# Determining function having first and second derivative

Tags: matlab

Im supposed to calculate function having :

f'(x) = x^2+x

f(10) = 86

f''(1) = 6

Is there a matlab way to find function having such features?

Comment: as you write you are *supposed to*, you should really try to *calculate* it and not let Matlab do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB is not really designed for Computer Algebra Systems (CAS) but can do [Numerical Integrals](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html).

However, your system sounds strange to me :

- First :

[image]

- And :

[image]

- So :

[image]

- But :

[image]

- Finally :

Are you sure about the validity of your system? Because it seems that there isn't any function that could verify it.